# PyQt5 Qthread Create

Tags: qt, pyqt5, qthread

**AttributeError: type object 'QThread' has no attribute 'create'**

Here is my code.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread

def fun(num):
    print(num)

thread1 = QThread.create(fun)
thread1.start()
```

But [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html) says there is a function called create since Qt 5.10. I am using PyQt5 5.11.3. Someone please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use worker objects by moving them to the thread using `QObject::moveToThread()`.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore    import QObject, pyqtSignal, QThread, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QProgressBar, QPushButton

class Worker(QObject):

    valueChanged = pyqtSignal(int)                   # Value change signal

    def run(self):
        print('thread id ->', int(QThread.currentThreadId()))
        for i in range(1, 101):
            print('value =', i)
            self.valueChanged.emit(i)
            QThread.msleep(100)


class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Window, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.progressBar = QProgressBar(self)
        self.progressBar.setRange(0, 100)
        layout.addWidget(self.progressBar)
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton('Open thread', self, clicked=self.onStart))

        # Current thread id
        print('main id = ', int(QThread.currentThreadId()))

        # Start thread update progress bar value
        self._thread = QThread(self)
        self._worker = Worker()
        self._worker.moveToThread(self._thread)        # Move to thread to execute
        self._thread.finished.connect(self._worker.deleteLater)
        self._worker.valueChanged.connect(self.progressBar.setValue)

    def onStart(self):
        print('main id -> ', int(QThread.currentThreadId()))
        self._thread.start()                            # Start thread
        QTimer.singleShot(1, self._worker.run)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        if self._thread.isRunning():
            self._thread.quit()

        del self._thread
        del self._worker
        super(Window, self).closeEvent(event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    w.setWindowTitle('Demo moveToThread')
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You so much for the quick reply.